# ¿No entiendo porque al validar el archivo del formulario entra en el trown si el formato es correcto?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Si pongo la validación de extensiones me da error. Envío una imagen jpg y si el formato es diferente a jpg pongo un error controlado pero la foto es jpg y no debo hacer eso.

Es un simple formulario html que envía los datos a una página php y si todo es correcto almacena la foto.

He visto a personas validar solo con el tipo así que como es mi primera validación no se cual es el método correcto.

HTML:

```
<input
type="file"
name="foto"
accept=".jpg,.png"
>
```

PHP:

```
function validate_form_file()
{
    /**
     * - Foto es el valor de name en el input de tipo archivo.
     */
    $_fileName    = $_FILES['foto']['name'];     // Capturamos el nombre del archivo a través de la propiedad name.
    $_filePath    = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']; // Capturamos la ruta temporal del archivo a través de la propiedad tpm_name.
    $_fileError   = $_FILES['foto']['error'];    // Capturamos el valor boolean que nos da la propiedad error si no se ha enviado nada.
    $_fileType    = $_FILES['foto']['type'];  // Capturamos el tipo de archivo que estamos subiendo.
    $_fileSize    = $_FILES['foto']['size'];     // Capturamos el tamaño del archivo mediante la propiedad size.
    $_fileMaxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1;             // Establece un tamaño máximo para el archivo, en concreto 1 Mb.

    echo $_fileType . '<br/>';
    /**
     * - Si se produce un error ejecutamos una salida controlada mediante throw.
     */
    if 
    (
        $_fileError === true       ||
        $_fileSize > $_fileMaxSize
    ) 
    {
        throw new Exception("¡ERROR! (hay un fallo con el archivo enviado o su tamaño).");
    }
    // No he podido solucionar este error.
    // else if 
    // (
    //     $_fileType != 'foto/jpg'   &&
    //     $_fileType != 'foto/png'   &&
    //     $_fileType != 'foto/gif'
    // ) 
    // {
    //     throw new Exception("¡ERROR! (hay un fallo con el archivo enviado, verifique si el formato es de tipo .gif .png .jpg).");
    // }
    else
    {
        /**
         * - Añadimos la ruta donde queremos que se guarde el fichero enviado.
         * - $_newPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/03_Task_UT2/1_sistema_ventas/fotos\"
         * - Con la barra invertida al final podemos añadir prefijo a las fotos.
         */
        $_newPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/03_Task_UT2/1_sistema_ventas/images/".$_fileName;
        // Traspasamos de la ruta temporal a la ruta local el archivo.
        move_uploaded_file($_filePath, "$_newPath");
        // Retornamos true porque la foto se guardo correctamente.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Veo que haz traducido los comentarios de tu código al inglés... Nuevamente te repetimos, estás en **SO en español**, por la cual deberías traducir tu pregunta **al español**, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="file" $name="foto" accept=".jpg,.png" validateimg($name);>








    <?php
    function validateimg($img){
    if (file_exists($img['tmp_name'])!= TRUE){
        throw new Exception("¡ERROR! (hay un fallo con el archivo enviado o su                 tamaño).");
    exit;}
    else{setimg($img); }
    function setimg($doc){
    //Configuración de imágenes
    

    $extensionesValidas = array("png", "jpg");           
    //Extensiones permitidas
    $errores = array();                                     
    $nombreArchivo = $doc['name'];             //parametros de archivo
    $filesize = $doc['size'];                  //parametros de archivo
    $directorioTemp = $doc['tmp_name'];        //parametros de archivo
    $tipoArchivo = $doc['type'];               //parametros de archivo
    $arrayArchivo = pathinfo($nombreArchivo);      
    $extension = $arrayArchivo['extension'];
    $directorioSubida = "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyectos/".$extension."/"; //ruta de                 subida
    // Comprobamos la extensión del archivo
    if(!in_array($extension, $extensionesValidas)){         //Validación de 
    extension valida
        $errores[] = "La extensión del archivo no es válida o no se ha subido ningún archivo";      //mensaje de error
    throw new Exception("¡ERROR! (hay un fallo con el archivo enviado, verifique si el formato es de tipo  .png .jpg).");
        exit;
    }
   
   
    // Renombramos el nombre del archivo
    
     $nombreArchivo = $arrayArchivo['filename'];
     $nombreArchivo = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $nombreArchivo);
     $nombreArchivo = $nombreArchivo . rand(1, 100);
    // Desplazamos el archivo si no hay errores
    if(empty($errores)){
    $nombreCompleto = $directorioSubida.$nombreArchivo.".".$extension;
    move_uploaded_file($directorioTemp, $nombreCompleto);}} ?>
```